# How can I do dynamically updated HighCharts with StockCharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts, diagram

I'd like to do this example: https://jsfiddle.net/t0n38px4/

Just I have ecg data. If I don't use stockChart the ecg is displayed good, but if I use I have something problem because stockhcart zooms too far. My chart options is here which equal to jsfiddle example just I changed series data and load events.

```
 this.chartOptions = {
          series: [
            {
              type: "line",
              data: (function(component) {
                var data = [],
                  i;
                for (i = 0; i < component.length; i += 1) {
                  const newData = component.addMoreData(); //push new [time, value]
                  const time = newData[0]; // get new time
                  const value = newData[1]; // get new value
                  data.push({
                    x: time,
                    y: value
                  });
                }
                return data;
              })(this)
            }
          ],
          chart: {
            events: {
              load: (function(component) {
                return function() {
                  var series = this.series[0];
                  setInterval(() => {
                    const newData = component.addMoreData(); //push new [time, value]
                    const time = newData[0]; // get new time
                    const value = newData[1]; // get new value
                    var x = time,
                      y = value;
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true, false); //false
                  }, 500);
                };
              })(this)
            }
          },
          rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [
              {
                count: 1,
                type: "minute",
                text: "1M"
              },
              {
                count: 5,
                type: "minute",
                text: "5M"
              },
              {
                type: "all",
                text: "All"
              }
            ],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
          },
          exporting: {
            enabled: false
          }
        };
```

Full code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t2evda

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, I would use the chart callback function instead of the `load`. event. 
Iside you might refer to the chart and use the `addPoint` method to add point to the series.

**Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-jtnr6g**
**API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint**

Comment: If I use this callback function I can't use stockChart

Comment: Why is that? I don't understand why wouldn't you use the stockChart?